# How can I report a tweet as spam with api?

Tags: api, twitter

I want to report a tweet as spam with API 1.1. In a similar way to how you can do it with iPhone & android apps.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API has a report_spam endpoint:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/users/report_spam

Comment: Is there any useful example in python ?

Comment: @j.doe Here's the Tweepy API: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#spam-reporting-methods